# Node SSH2 connecting to a router

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, npm

I am creating an app that can SSH into the router at my work and take attendance of the students based off of connection to the WiFi. I have the log in info and can open up a terminal and SSH into it using the username and password and run commands to get the list of connected devices.

How ever when I set it up using SSH with Node.js I run into an error and can not run any commands and the router kicks my connection. I assume it is when I try and run a command but can not prove that. Below is my code and the debug log. Any help filtering through this would be appreciated.

```
    DEBUG: Local ident: 'SSH-2.0-ssh2js0.1.19'
    DEBUG: Client: Trying 192.168.0.24 on port 22 ...
    DEBUG: Client: Connected
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_INIT
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_GREETING
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_HEADER
    DEBUG: Remote ident: 'SSH-2.0-dropbear_2013.59'
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing KEXINIT
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:220,padLen:10,remainLen:216
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: KEXINIT
    DEBUG: Comparing KEXINITs ...
    DEBUG: (local) KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    DEBUG: (remote) KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au
    DEBUG: KEX algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    DEBUG: (local) Host key formats: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    DEBUG: (remote) Host key formats: ssh-rsa
    DEBUG: Host key format: ssh-rsa
    DEBUG: (local) Client->Server ciphers: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour
    DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server ciphers: 3des-ctr,3des-cbc
    DEBUG: Client->Server Cipher: 3des-cbc
    DEBUG: (local) Server->Client ciphers: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour
    DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client ciphers: 3des-ctr,3des-cbc
    DEBUG: Server->Client Cipher: 3des-cbc
    DEBUG: (local) Client->Server HMAC algorithms: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
    DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server HMAC algorithms: hmac-sha1
    DEBUG: Client->Server HMAC algorithm: hmac-sha1
    DEBUG: (local) Server->Client HMAC algorithms: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
    DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client HMAC algorithms: hmac-sha1
    DEBUG: Server->Client HMAC algorithm: hmac-sha1
    DEBUG: (local) Client->Server compression algorithms: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server compression algorithms: none
    DEBUG: Client->Server compression algorithm: none
    DEBUG: (local) Server->Client compression algorithms: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    DEBUG: (remote) Server->Client compression algorithms: none
    DEBUG: Server->Client compression algorithm: none
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing KEXDH_INIT
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:572,padLen:4,remainLen:568
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: KEXDH_REPLY
    DEBUG: Checking host key format
    DEBUG: Checking signature format
    DEBUG: Verifying host fingerprint
    DEBUG: Host accepted by default (no verification)
    DEBUG: Verifying signature
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing NEWKEYS
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:10,remainLen:8
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: NEWKEYS
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing SERVICE_REQUEST (ssh-userauth)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:28,padLen:10,remainLen:24
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: SERVICE_ACCEPT
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing USERAUTH_REQUEST (none)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:20,padLen:5,remainLen:16
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: USERAUTH_FAILURE
    DEBUG: Client: none auth failed
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing USERAUTH_REQUEST (password)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:10,remainLen:8
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: USERAUTH_SUCCESS
    Client :: ready
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_OPEN (0, session)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:28,padLen:10,remainLen:24
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_REQUEST (0, exec)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:6,remainLen:8
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_SUCCESS (0)
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_DATA (0)
    DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_EOF (0)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:28,padLen:6,remainLen:24
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA (0)
    STDERR: Aborted

    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:6,remainLen:8
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_EOF (0)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:36,padLen:10,remainLen:32
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
    DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_REQUEST (0, exit-status)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKET
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting
    DEBUG: Parser: pktLen:12,padLen:6,remainLen:8
    DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATA
    DEBUG: Parser: Decrypting

DEBUG: Parser: HMAC size:20
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY
DEBUG: Parser: Verifying MAC
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAVERIFY (Valid HMAC)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETDATAAFTER, packet: CHANNEL_CLOSE (0)
DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing CHANNEL_CLOSE (0)
DEBUG: Parser: IN_PACKETBEFORE (expecting 8)
Stream :: close

DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing DISCONNECT (BY_APPLICATION)
```

> ```
> const express = require('express'),
>   Client = require('ssh2').Client;
>
> let MacAdresses = [];
> let conn = new Client();
>
> conn.on('ready', () => {
>   console.log('Client :: ready');
>   conn.exec('show clients', function(err, stream) {
>     if (err) throw err;
>     stream.on('close', function() {
>       console.log('Stream :: close');
>       console.log(MacAdresses.toString('utf8'));
>       conn.end();
>     }).on('data', function(data) {
>       console.log('asfasfsaf', data)
>       MacAdresses.push(data);
>       console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
>     }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
>       console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
>     });
>     stream.end('ls -l\nexit\n');
>   });
> }).connect({
>   host: '192.168.0.24',
>   port: 22,
>   username: '******',
>   password: '******',
>   debug: console.log,
>   algorithms: {
>     cipher : [
>       'aes128-ctr','aes192-ctr','aes256-ctr','arcfour256','arcfour128',
>                 'aes128-cbc','3des-cbc','blowfish-cbc','cast128-cbc','aes192-cbc',
>                 'aes256-cbc','arcfour'],
>     hmac: ['hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96']
> }
> });
> ```

Comment: Did you try removing the `stream.end('ls -l\nexit\n');`? Typically you won't be doing that for an `exec()` (unless you're executing bash with `exec()`, which is not common).

Comment: I did try and remove that line, but from what I can tell I got the same error.

Comment: With the `stream.end()` still removed, you could try using a pty in case the remote process is expecting a tty: `conn.exec('show clients', {pty: true}, function(err, stream) { ... })`

Comment: Awesome, I have a connection to the router, thanks to your help. But now it won't run the command I have as the first argument 'show clients.' I do get some output from the terminal however. I get the Mac address of the router with # after it. It is the text that comes before each new line when you type in commands. The connection stays open but I can not type in any commands and have them execute.

If possible I would just like the 'show clients' to run then the connection can close.